# footprint size for a standalone Julia app in a containerized environment like Docker/k8s

Tags: docker, julia

I'm curious about this. I normally write Java and Go microservices in docker/k8s on AWS and I started looking at using Julia.
Does anyone have any pointers and experiences in a dockerized env?